# can't scroll to an element using mouse actions() in protractor jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, protractor

Can't scroll to an element using mouse actions in protractor jasmine framework:

```
var elm_xpath = browser.element(by.xpath('//*[@id="hot"]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[15]'));
browser.actions().mouseMove(elm_xpath).perform();
```

Comment: firstly, you should say are you using Control Flow or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try scrolling to a particular element using:

```
function scroll() {
   var scrolldown = element.all(by.css(".className"));
   browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
      browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', 
      scrolldown.getWebElement());
   });
}

scroll();
```

You can replace .className with your respective selector to find that element.
Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thamks @Sandy_22.

Comment: @Kranthi Could you please accept the above answer if it works for you. Others can benefit from this. Thanks